# Fast calculation of quadratic form in matlab

Tags: performance, matlab, quadratic

I have the following case:

```
    Y(i) - m x 1 vecotr , i = 1,...,N
    A(i) - m x m symmetric matrix , i = 1,...,N
    H(i,j) = 0.5*(Y(i)-Y(j))'( A(i)^-1+A(j)^-1)(Y(i)-Y(j)) |i,j = 1,...,N
```

Currently I calculated the inverse of A(i) separately and H with two 'for' loops:

```
    for i= 1:N
       A_inv(:,:,i) = inv(A(:,:,i)); 
    end

    H= zeros(N,N);
    for j=1:N
        for i=(j+1):N
            x = Y(:,1,j)-Y(:,1,i);
            H(j,i) = 0.5*(x'*(A_inv(:,:,i)+A_inv(:,:,j))*x);
            H(i,j) = H(j,i);
        end
    end
```

I have not found a way to optimize the code, the answers I've seen in the forums are for cases which A is constant and does not depend on the indexes.
Is there a more efficient way to compute it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what sizes are involved, but the following approach should almost always be both faster and more accurate, since it does not require a matrix inversion (which is something one should always try to avoid):

```
clearvars 

% Build sample inputs

N = 100;
m = 500;

Y = randn(m, 1, N);
for i = N:-1:1
    t = randn(m);
    A(:,:,i) = t' * t;
end

% original method

tic
for i= 1:N
   A_inv(:,:,i) = inv(A(:,:,i)); 
end

H= zeros(N,N);
for j=1:N
    for i=(j+1):N
        x = Y(:,1,j)-Y(:,1,i);
        H(j,i) = 0.5*(x'*(A_inv(:,:,i)+A_inv(:,:,j))*x);
        H(i,j) = H(j,i);
    end
end
toc

H_old = H;

clear A_inv H x


% proposed method

tic

for i = N:-1:1
   Ai_invY = A(:,:,i) \ Y(:,:);
   H(i,:) = Y(:,i)' * Ai_invY(:,i) ... % Yi' * Ai_inv * Yi
          - 2 * Y(:,i)' * Ai_invY ...  % - Yi' * Ai_inv * Yj - Yj' * Ai_inv * Yi
          + sum(Y(:,:) .* Ai_invY, 1); % + Yj' * Ai_inv * Yj
end
H = (H + H')/2;

toc

% check difference

plot(H_old(:) - H(:))
```

In my laptop I get 10.3 seconds for the original method, and 0.44 seconds for the proposed one.